# Cloudlinux, GRUB 0.97, software RAID, won't automatically boot

Tags: software-raid, grub, cloudlinux

My server is running Cloudlinux as has a software RAID mirror (/dev/md2 made from /dev/sda and /dev/sdb) mounted on /

It's been running fine, but after simulating a raid failure and rebuilding the mirror, it won't reboot by itself.  Instead if dumps me at the grub> prompt.

It will boot fine if I do this:

```
grub> root (hd0,1)
grub> kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/md2
grub> initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64.img
grub> boot
```

But no matter what I try I can't get it to boot automatically.  It's like it's not seeing /boot/grub/grub.conf (which is symlinked to menu.lst)  /boot/grub/grub.conf looks like this:

```
default=0
timeout=2

title CloudLinux Server (2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64)
   root (hd0,1)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/md2 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us  ro nohz=off
   initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64.img
```

I have reinstalled grub on both drives with grub-install, I've also done the following:

```
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
 (hd0,1)
 (hd1,1)
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
device (hd0) /dev/sda
grub> root (hd0,1)
root (hd0,1)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
grub> setup (hd0)
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage2" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
 Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd0)"... failed (this is not fatal)
 Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd0,1)"... failed (this is not fatal)
 Running "install /boot/grub/stage1 (hd0) /boot/grub/stage2 p /boot/grub/grub.conf "... succeeded
Done.
grub> device (hd1) /dev/sdb
device (hd1) /dev/sdb
grub> root (hd1,1)
root (hd1,1)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
grub> setup (hd1)
setup (hd1)
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage2" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
 Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd1)"... failed (this is not fatal)
 Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd1,1)"... failed (this is not fatal)
 Running "install /boot/grub/stage1 (hd1) /boot/grub/stage2 p /boot/grub/grub.conf "... succeeded
Done.
```

Any ideas?